# AdMob rewarded video ad in Swift

Tags: swift, admob, chartboost

I'm looking at adding a rewarded video ad to my app that is written entirely in swift. I believe the setup of the web side of things is correct because when I downloaded the Objective C example app and put in my ad id the video showed up correctly. However, when running the same setup in Swift I get returned

```
Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

I've only had ONE time where it actually returned a video.  I'm using Chartboost.

Another interesting point is that if I used chart boost directly it seemed to work.

Also, banners work perfectly fine through AdMob in the same app.

Request I Make

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().loadRequest(request, withAdUnitID: "AdUnitID")
```

Comment: I noticed that they don't have a swift example for reward videos and am wondering if that's because it's not ready.  I don't see any docs stating that Swift is unsupported for reward videos though.  Does anyone know? Maybe I missed it somewhere.

Comment: So it looks like I can't set testDevices for a reward based video ad.  If I take that out the request works.